# MCISendCommand Can't find file, but Fstream can so I know it exists, why?

Tags: file-not-found, mci

I'm trying to play a midi file using MCISendCommand but I keep getting a DWORD error code 275 (File Not found). I have since placed the relevant code inside a fstream open call which DOES find the file. I then close the file to allow the MCISendCommand code to access it but it still cannot find the file.

Here is the relevant code:

```
fstream f;
f.open(szMIDIFileName);
if(f.is_open())
    // Then the file exists
{
    f.close();
  // See if the MIDI player needs to be opened
  if (m_uiMIDIPlayerID == 0)
  {
    // Open the MIDI player by specifying the device and filename
    MCI_OPEN_PARMS mciOpenParms;
    mciOpenParms.lpstrDeviceType = "sequencer";
    mciOpenParms.lpstrElementName = szMIDIFileName; //The name of the file passed in as a param
    if (mciSendCommand(NULL, MCI_OPEN, MCI_OPEN_TYPE | MCI_OPEN_ELEMENT,
      (DWORD_PTR)&mciOpenParms) == 0)
      // Get the ID for the MIDI player
      m_uiMIDIPlayerID = mciOpenParms.wDeviceID;
    else
      // There was a problem, so just return
     // This is where I keep ending up in my code with DWORD error 275
      return;
  }
}
```

I should also mention that this code works in a sample project from a textbook of mine "Beginning Game Programming" by Michael Morrison. As far as I can tell all project properties are identical. For some reason, however, the code does not work for me in my own project, even though I have since copy/pasted every single line of code over from the sample project (there is not that much, 3/5 small classes).

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might want to try:

1. from the [msdn remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743441(v=vs.85).aspx)

> To use automatic type selection (via the entries in the registry),
>   assign the filename and file extension to the lpstrElementName member
>   of the structure identified by lpOpen, set the lpstrDeviceType member
>   to NULL, and set the MCI_OPEN_ELEMENT flag.

In other words, let the system choose for you the device type, rather than setting it to "Sequencer".

2. The other thing you can try - some API don't like blank spaces in the path. So you might want to try this theory out by moving your media file to C:\ and remove all (possible) spaces you might have in your file name, and see if that's it.